# Read a .csv file with Sparklyr in R

Tags: r, csv, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have couple of `.csv` files in `C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents` which are more than 2 GB in size. I want to use Apache Spark to read the data out of them in R. I am using Microsoft R Open 3.3.1 with Spark 2.0.1.

I am stuck with reading the `.csv` files with the function `spark_read_csv(...)` defined in `Sparklyr` package. It is asking for a file path which starts with `file://`. I want to know the proper file path for my case starting with `file://` and ends with the file name which are in `.../Documents` directory.

Comment: Isn't it 'file:///C:/Users/USER_NAME/Documents/FILENAME.csv' ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case it was necessary for the .csv file to be put into the hdfs file system before calling it with spark_read_csv.

I think you probably have a similar problem.

If your cluster is also running with hdfs you need to use:

hdfs dfs -put

Best,
Felix

Comment: If the directory is in hdfs, you can create a hive-mapping (create external table ...) and read all CSVs at once using `spark_read_csv`